# Bulk-copy linked rows using JPARepository over mysql

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, spring-data-jpa, data-manipulation

I have linked rows like following where links is a list of primary keys of the same table:

> **id** | **label** | **links**
>
> 1 | label1 | null
>
> 2 | label2 | null
>
> 3 | label3 | 1,2

I need to bulk copy thousands of these rows keeping the links intact (the new list will have new ids).

**Edit 1**
Suppose the above rows are copied as follows

> **id** | **label** | **links**
>
> 91 | label1 | null
>
> 92 | label2 | null
>
> 93 | label3 | 1,2 (these should be 91,92 and now 1,2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
drop procedure if exists BulkInsert;
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE BulkInsert()   
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
WHILE (i <= 100) DO
    INSERT INTO tableName (label, links) VALUES ('label1', null);
     INSERT INTO tableName (label, links) VALUES ('label2', null);
     INSERT INTO tableName (label, links) VALUES ('label3', '1,2');
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END;
//  

CALL BulkInsert();
```

Comment: I need to copy existing rows